# What are possible causes of systemd error "Failed to enqueue OnFailure= job: Resource deadlock avoided"?

Tags: systemd

My systemd `onFailure` tasks failed to run, and I see this in the `system` journal:

> : Failed to enqueue OnFailure= job: Resource deadlock avoided

What are possible causes that could trigger this message and prevent from my `OnFailure=` task from running?

I'm using systemd v229

Comment: My guess based on the error message would be a circular dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly happens here is: You trigger shutdown.target, systemd uses job mode 'replace-irreversibly' for it. The unit fails because this target conflicts with every other unit, and triggers a stop for them. Meanwhile, your unit must have failed, so it triggers OnFailure= unit. Now, by default, this too Conflicts= with shutdown.target, hence will trigger a stop for it. But, since job mode was replace-irreversibly, it cannot cancel that job and replace it, and systemd considers this is a conflicting transaction, hence it is aborted. manager_add_job fails, and this bus error is mapped to EDEADLK errno, so you see Resource deadlock avoided string.

Answer (score 0):

This can case be triggered in a system configuration that is designed to boot up a system, run a single task and then shut off. The systemd service that also contains the failing `OnFailure=` task might also contain:

```
ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/poweroff
```

There is a deadlock in that to finish shutting down the unit the poweroff commands needs to run. But for the poweroff command to finish running, it needs to stop the unit.

Meanwhile, the `OnFailure=` job is trying run while this deadlock is occurring.

Ultimately, it seems the `poweroff` action soon "wins" the deadlock, also pre-empting the `OnFailure=` task from running.

An alternate solution on AWS is to set a CloudWatch alarm on the instance. The alarm will have the option to "Take Action: Shutdown" if the Max CPU on the instance is less than 1% CPU for 15 minutes.